# vscode - for file type, make tab always just make 4 spaces

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

From my understanding, vscode's default tab behavior is to tab to the next column that is divisible by your tab length. So if my tab length is 4 and I am at column 1, it will add 3 spaces. Great!

For a certain file type, I would like to override this behavior and have tab always make *exactly* 4 spaces, rather than taking me to the next divisible column. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

VScode currently spaces the cursor to column 5 from column 1. So it is adding 4 spaces to wherever you hit the tab key. I just typed a comment line like so
1234567890 and in the line under that I hit the tab key and the curson went to space 5 and space 9. So it appears to be doing what you want. I haven't set anything. In the settings file you can see the following description.

// The number of spaces a tab is equal to. This setting is overridden based on the file contents when `editor.detectIndentation` is on.

"editor.tabSize": 4,

Comment: ... huh. Mine is rounding to column. Any idea what setting could be causing that?

Comment: Good question. Maybe a setting is overriding this.  I'll look further to see if I can find anything.

Comment: I've searched but everything I find that could affect it is already turned on and doesn't affect anything when I run it.